# JavaScript Coding Style: curly brace after multiline condition

Tags: javascript, coding-style

In my company projects, curly braces in JavaScript are always on the same line after "if" condition.
Considering multiline condition in the next example, do you think indentation of the line "list[i].Position++;" looks ok? Looks a bit odd to me, because visually it has the same indentation as condition lines.

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].Position < previousPosition &&
        list[i].Position >= savedPosition) {
        list[i].Position++;
    }
}
```

Would you do something with this code regarding coding style?

Comment: I personally would indent `list[i].Position++;` one more tab stop because I think that would be more readable, but this is entirely a personal opinion thing.

Comment: Sometimes with things like this I'd consider moving the condition into it's own line below the parenthesis, and closing the parenthesis on a new line and have the curly brace on the same line as the close parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation is irrelevant, but I would read list.length once, rather than on each iteration.

```
for (var i = 0,L=list.length; i < L; i++)
```

Comment: That's a nice catch! It's not as readable for my taste, but it's definitely a bit faster. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would do something with this. I wouldn't say the issue is with the braces though.
Multi-line conditions are difficult to read, I'd recommend pulling that out to a separate function.

```
function isRightPosition(position, previous, saved) {
    return position < previous
         && position >= saved;
}

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(isRightPosition(list[i].Position, previous, saved))
        list[i].Position++;
}
```

You could also intent the body of the if further, to prevent confusion with the condition.

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].Position < previousPosition &&
        list[i].Position >= savedPosition) {
            list[i].Position++;
    }
}
```

You can also move the ampersands, which sometimes helps:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].Position < previousPosition
        && list[i].Position >= savedPosition) {
            list[i].Position++;
    }
}
```

It's all personal opinion though. Do what you feel is best (or consistent).

Comment: I have 2 slightly different conditions, making 2 functions for them is a bit of an overkill, for my taste. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @JoeSmith I think a lot of people don't create enough functions. A function name often says a lot more about the intention than some conditions. It's certainly easier, for me, to read English words like 'if' and 'is right position' than trying to work out what the conditions *mean*.